# Ionic 4 FirebaseX Push notification Stuck at SplashScreen (IOS)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I have a working push notification on android, but when I tried it to IOS(physical device) my app just stuck in splash screen. I know there is a conflict between firebase and my other plugins, I just can't find it since there is no error throwing on my debug. It's like I am fixing in the dark

Here's the log I got from the Xcode:

```
Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
 Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
 [CDVTimer][console] 0.044942ms
 [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.040054ms
 Unlimited access to network resources
 [CDVTimer][intentand/navigationfilter] 1.261115ms
 [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.039935ms
 [CDVTimer][file] 1.174092ms
 Starting Firebase plugin
 [CDVTimer][firebaseplugin] 1.145005ms
 [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.092983ms
 CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
 CDVIonicKeyboard: WARNING!!: Keyboard plugin works better with WK
 [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 0.707030ms
 _hasPermission: NO
 [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 3.234029ms
 [CDVTimer][statusbar] 3.214955ms
 [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.458956ms
 [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 12.398005ms
 FirebasePlugin[native] LOG: GoogleService-Info.plist found, setup: [FIRApp configureWithOptions]
 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60402000 started
 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:

[Crashlytics] Version 3.14.0 (144)
6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
FirebasePlugin[native] LOG: Enter foreground: FCM direct channel = false
FirebasePlugin[native] LOG: didReceiveRegistrationToken: dd9mOdE2pkghisuLiF7qYg:APA91bGC-oZ60V6hvCCzu_1lcJDknQQoeNnGZsh1pONuhQfPzU1fP1vs7xVm_hnuhqihKNdm-GpRtKgDlQf_89_IsOeaTCjQd_F4flXOG4BMUgWegYRM1JDzcUflm2OzPN5U6cx74GCr
FirebasePlugin[native] LOG: tokenRefreshNotification: dd9mOdE2pkghisuLiF7qYg:APA91bGC-oZ60V6hvCCzu_1lcJDknQQoeNnGZsh1pONuhQfPzU1fP1vs7xVm_hnuhqihKNdm-GpRtKgDlQf_89_IsOeaTCjQd_F4flXOG4BMUgWegYRM1JDzcUflm2OzPN5U6cx74GCr
6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

My plugin list

```
call-number 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-androidx 2.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.1 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.6 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 9.1.2-cli "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 3.0.1 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player 2.4.0 "CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer"
cordova-sms-plugin 1.0.0 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

My Ionic Info:

```
  Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : not installed
   @capacitor/core : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.1 
   native-run  : 0.3.0 (update available: 1.0.0)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.4
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708
```

Comment: Did you fix the problem? Because I have exactly the same issue

Comment: Yes I fix the problem. I move to another firebase push library

Comment: @aJaysanity please, which library are you using right now? It works on Android and iOS?